# jQuery AJAX return limited results from REST end point

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Using jQuery AJAX I am trying to return limited results from a call to a RESTful end point. Without having to post to the server to return limited results to my RESTful api.

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: '/showroom-event-gallery-api',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Is there anyway I can add a method that will only return 10 objects from the JSON that is retrieved from the RESTful API? At the moment that end point has over 200 results returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   url: '/showroom-event-gallery-api',
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.slice(0,10));
   }
});
```